# awk command in unix to retain lines with either of two specific character values in a column

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am new to unix and looking to parse lines from the 7th field of a tab delimited `gff` file using `awk` [See file format here](http://useast.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html?redirect=no#fields). The 7th field (`strand`) has characters `+`, `-`, or `.` and I am interested in retaining only lines with valid strand information (`+`or `-`).  I used the following code:

`cat PGSC_DM_V403_genes.gff | awk '{if ($7!=".") print $0;}'` > PGSC_DM_V403_genes_valid_strand.gff`

and received the following sample output:

ST4.03ch01      Cufflinks/GLEAN intron  261697  261770  .       -       .       ID=PGSC0003DMI400097777;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653
ST4.03ch01      Cufflinks/GLEAN intron  261849  263327  .       -       .       ID=PGSC0003DMI400097778;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653
ST4.03ch01      Cufflinks/GLEAN intron  263420  263583  .       -       .       ID=PGSC0003DMI400097779;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653
ST4.03ch01      Cufflinks/GLEAN intron  263635  265374  .       -       .       ID=PGSC0003DMI400097780;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     265375  265579  .       -       0       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     263584  263634  .       -       2       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     263328  263419  .       -       2       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     261771  261848  .       -       0       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     261539  261696  .       -       0       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     261241  261342  .       -       1       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     261048  261165  .       -       1       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     260219  260271  .       -       0       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     260075  260140  .       -       1       ID=PGSC0003DMC400039506;Parent=PGSC0003DMT400058653;name="Plasmalemma
ST4.03ch01      BestORF CDS     259678  259722  .       -       1       ID=PGSC0

Visualizing in the tab delimited format made it difficult to see that the command had worked appropriately and that the 7th field now only contained `+` and `-`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Comment: What do you mean by `column 7`? Do you mean the 7th character on the line? Or that there are fields separated by commas, tabs or spaces?

Comment: I added that @EdMorton, for future folks looking to parse their `.gff` files with `awk`. Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Well... I was able to give 100% working answer based on the information provided. With the caveat that we don't know the delim. To each their own, I suppose.

Comment: I apologize sincerely for the lack of information. JNevill was most gracious and I have amended the post to hopefully provide appropriate detail.

Answer (score 2):

That should be pretty simple in awk.

```
awk '$7=="+" || $7=="-"' yourfile.gff
```

Assuming you have a default delimiter here, if not use `-F` flag to set that. We don't need to use `{print $0}` here since that's the default action, so all we do is test `$7` for the two values you are looking for and that's that.

Since this is a `.gff` file, really you just want to drop records where the 7th field (`strand`) is a period character. So instead (as you noted in the comments here) you can use:

```
awk '$7!="."' yourfile.gff
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this command (awk '$7=="+" || $7=="-"' PGSC_DM_V403_genes.gff > PGSC_DM_V403_genes_valid_strand.txt) there are still "." and "0" in the 7th column when I inspect the newly created file

Comment: Perhaps you have different number of fields on each line?  Try `awk '!a[NF]++{print NF}'` which will print number of unique field counts as `awk` sees it.

Comment: I suspect that because a gff is a tab delimited file, the output is also tab delimited and it just looks like the 7th field has the `0`, but in fact that's the 8th field. The `gff` standard suggests that only `+` and `-` are allowed in the 7th field, so if your file has a 0 in the 7th field your file might be bad.

Comment: To test my assumption, try `awk '$7=="+" || $7=="-" {print $7}' PGSC_DM_V403_genes.gff `. You should only see `+` and `-` outputted.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and your assumption is correct. I apologize for my initial lack of pertinent information.

Comment: That should work as well. I think `awk` is doing what you want, it just doesn't look like it because tabs are hard to see as delimiters since they vary in how many characters they take up. Also, you can try `awk 'BEGIN { OFS="|"} $7!="." {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' PGSC_DM_V403_genes.gff` and that will swap out the tabs for a pipe and make the individual fields much easier to see.

Comment: No prob. I thought your question had plenty of info. I just edited to add the file format of a `gff` for folks stumbling on this question in the future.

Comment: I added that `$7!="."` logic to the answer here since that's more succinct and folks on here love them some refactored code.

Comment: The pipe has allowed me to properly visualize the 7th column and it is appropriately filtered. Many thanks!